# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo to create tabMenu

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I´m trying to launch other activity in my app when i´m doing login in my app. This second activity have a `tabMenu` with a `viewPager2` but when my app tray load this activity launch error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.citysportgym/com.example.citysportgym.ProfileActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
```

i´m building a personaliced class Adapter:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter

class MyAdapter (fragmentManager: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {
    private val fragmentList = ArrayList<Fragment>()
    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return fragmentList[position]
    }

    fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        fragmentList.add(fragment)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return fragmentList.size
    }
}
```

i have a class singleton:

```
import android.app.Application
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley

/**
 * Created by Belal on 5/16/2017.
 */
class VolleySingleton : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
    }

    val requestQueue: RequestQueue? = null
        get() {
            if (field == null) {
                return Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext)
            }
            return field
        }

    fun <T> addToRequestQueue(request: Request<T>) {
        request.tag = TAG
        requestQueue?.add(request)
    }

    companion object {
        private val TAG = VolleySingleton::class.java.simpleName
        @get:Synchronized var instance: VolleySingleton? = null
            private set
    }
}
```

i have a object with my Endpoint to connect MYSQL

```
object EndPoint {
    private val URL_ROOT = "http://192.168.1.112:8080/webservices/index.php"
    val URL = URL_ROOT
}
```

and in my MainActivity i have my actionButton to call my function login a use my singleton:

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener {
            login(editTextEmail!!.getText().toString(),editTextPassword!!.getText().toString())
        }
    }

    // function login
    private fun login(email:String, password:String) {
        //creating volley string request
        val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, EndPoint.URL,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->

                try {
                    Log.i("eee", response)
                    //init profile activity if not have error
                    val myIntent = Intent(this, ProfileActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(myIntent)
                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            },

            object : Response.ErrorListener {
                override fun onErrorResponse(volleyError: VolleyError) {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, volleyError.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            })

        {
            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                params.put("email", email)
                params.put("password", password)
                return params
            }
        }
        //adding request to queue
        VolleySingleton.instance?.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest)
    }
```

This login ok, i can show my messages in my webservices and all it´s ok. My problem it´s here:

```
Log.i("eee", response)
                    //init profile activity if not have error
                    val myIntent = Intent(this, ProfileActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(myIntent)
```

When app initiallice my activity, i´m building my tabMenu and send to this method all information...

```
private var tabTitle = arrayOf("Perfil", "Actividades", "Membresia")

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        var pager = findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.viewPager2)
        var tabLayout = findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.profileLayout)
        pager.adapter = MyAdapter(supportFragmentManager, lifecycle)

        TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, pager) { tab, position ->
            tab.text = tabTitle[position]
        }.attach()

        binding = ActivityProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
```

But return in this line `pager.adapter = MyAdapter(supportFragmentManager, lifecycle)` my error

I think that my class it´s not yet created and for this returned my error. How i can solve this?

Thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english

Comment: You need to call `setContentView()` _before_ trying to use `findViewById()` in `onCreate()`. As it is now, `findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.viewPager2)` is returning null, and it's crashing at `pager.adapter = MyAdapter(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem with:

```
// ACTION BUTTON LOGIN
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, ProfileActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("key", "Kotlin")
            startActivity(intent)
            login(editTextEmail!!.getText().toString(), editTextPassword!!.getText().toString())
        }
```

An in my function login i´m calling to my new layout:

```
val intent = Intent(this, ProfileActivity::class.java)
                            intent.putExtra("key", "Kotlin")
                            startActivity(intent)
```

In my new Activity in function onCreate:

```
// pager show content
        var pager = findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.viewPagerProfile)
        // tabLayout it´s TabsMenu
        var tabLayout = findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.profileMenu)
        // Personaliced Adaprter
        pager.adapter = MyAdapter(supportFragmentManager, lifecycle)

        TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, pager) { tab, position ->
            tab.text = tabTitle[position]
        }.attach()
```